# Begginer Python learner doesn't know why import "json" doesn't work

Tags: json, file, import

I'm learning from Youtube videos and one of the sections is called "JSON". Now when he imports "json", he gets a response in the output. When I do it all I get is :

```
"Process finished with exit code 0"
```

Now why does this happen and what am I doing wrong?

The code:

```js
import _json

person = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "hasChildren": False, "titles": ["engineer", "programmer"]}

personjson = json.dumps(person)
print(personjson)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code without errors so that each instruction is on a new line.

```
import json

person = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "hasChildren": False, "titles": ["engineer", "programmer"]}

personjson = json.dumps(person)

print(personjson)
```

This should work it is possible that this is not a code problem.

Comment: For me, this code works and prints in the console personjson.  This is not a code problem.   Maybe reinstalling python will help. If you are using pre-release try to install the stable release of python e.g. 3.9.6.